# SAS creating a count from other variable

Tags: sas

I have the following column

```
   Var_1    
   3456
   3456
   3456
   6
   6
   71
   71
   71
   71
```

I want to create another variable from this data that will give me a count of how many times each number is repeated So the variable will look like this:

```
       Count
        3
        2
        4
```

I have no idea or clue how to proceed on this. Is there anything in Proc Freq I can use?

Comment: Do you want to count repeats across the whole column or just within each run of consecutive identical values?

Comment: Have you looked into what you might be able to use?

Comment: Do you want a new table or included with your original table? Proc Freq, Proc SQL and Proc Means are some of the most common ways.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution: proc sql:

```
data tbl;
input var1;
cards;
3456
3456
3456
6
6
71
71
71
71
;
run;

proc sql;
create table tbl2 as
select var1,
       count(var1) as count
from tbl
group by var1
;
quit;
```

If you literally just want that column (count), you could just query the count(var1), but not sure why you would want a column displaying a count with no value attached. If you actually want to create an individual macro var for the count of each value, you could use `proc sql select into:` ...if that is what you are asking.

Comment: How can I turn this into a marco if I want to do it for different data sets? 

So instead of running the same proc sql different times for different datasets, I can just do some sort of a macro call?

Comment: You would just macro the proc sql part and use the data set name (that you want to create) and the variable (var you want to count) as the parameters. Then call it out...some thing like %count(table,var);

Comment: Interesting. I didn't know I could use the proc sql withing a macro

Comment: It wouldn't be within the macro, you would be using proc-sql as part of the macro. I mean...you CAN use macros in proc-sql, but I don't believe that is what you are attempting...this is assuming that you wrote a typo and meant to say "within"...

Comment: right...so you would take that code (starting with the proc sql...beginning your macro statement....include the proc sql...then end it with your %mend...just set your parameters accordingly.

Comment: Okay...This is what I meant. 
    %Macro count (var=, table=)
     proc sql;
                            create table &table as
                             select &var,
                             count(&var) as count
                              from tbl
                              group by &var;
                              quit;
     %mend
     % count (var=Var_1, table=Table1);
     %count (var=Var_2,  Table=table2);

Answer (score 0):

I think it's my fault to not have written the question clearly. The purpose of my code is to count the number of job ads an advertiser has put online. Now I have a column for advertiser (say McDonald), but there is no column that has a specific number of how many ad jobs McDonald has put up. They only have a value like the (Var_1), where it represents a code for a specific job they have put up. So I am basically trying to count all of the codes (Var_1) put up by advertiser, and then sum them all up to get a total number for the number of jobs put up. I have looked a lot online, but haven't found a solution. I thought I could use Proc Freq and Proc Means to get the value of "N" for the Var_1 and just add it all up to come up with a total number. I looked through Proc Sql, but I am not familiar with it. So I wasn't sure if it would work.